notification.findMembers taking too much time
I've developed a Teams bot app in TypeScript using the Teams Toolkit. The app is designed to be installed in the channel scope but also needs to send notifications to individual members (e.g. personal messages and links). To achieve this, I'm using the built-in function notificationApp.notification.findMember.
Currently, app installation data is stored in a blobStorage on my Azure Storage account. However, I'm facing a performance issue. The findMember function internally:

Retrieves all installations.
Checks if each installation is valid.
Fetches all members and filters them based on a predicate.

While this process runs quickly on my development account (6 members), it takes 90s in production with 1,900 members.
To address this, I want to maintain a database where email is the key, and all member objects are stored. The database would be refreshed periodically or upon specific events. I have two questions regarding this approach:

Handling Large Member Sets Efficiently: If I use an Azure Function with a cron job to refresh the database, how can I optimize it for large datasets (e.g. 10,000–50,000 members)? Is there a way to work only on the delta (changes since the last refresh)?

Refreshing on Installation Events: If I refresh the database whenever a new installation occurs (e.g. using onInstallationUpdateAdd), is there a way to directly fetch member objects within this function?


